# How to check my RAM configuration (Windows 7)?

Tags: ram, cpu-architecture

I would like to check my RAM configuration.

I know it is easy to check the total RAM installed on a computer (eg 32 GB), but is there an easy way to check in Windows if the RAM is e.g. 2x16 GB, 4x8 GB, 8x4 GB or 16x2 GB?

Thank you

Comment: You should ask this on http://superuser.com. But as answer you can use programs like: http://www.piriform.com/speccy

Comment: Thanks, I now asked on this website.

Comment: The answer to this question is now here: http://superuser.com/questions/650208/how-to-check-my-ram-configuration-windows-7/650212?noredirect=1#comment818524_650212

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple utility called CPU-Z that will tell you almost anything you need to know, check it out at http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html. I do not believe there is a similar way to see this information from Windows itself.
If you have access to it, you can usually see this information in the BIOS as well.